# Generic extension method returning IEnumerable<T> without using reflection

Tags: c#, generics

Consider this snippet of code:

```
public static class MatchCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable<T>(this MatchCollection mc)
    {
        return new T[mc.Count];
    }
}
```

And this class:

```
public class Ingredient
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way to magically transform a `MatchCollection` object to a collection of `Ingredient`? The use-case would look something like this:

```
var matches = new Regex("([a-z])+,?").Matches("tomato,potato,carrot");

var ingredients = matches.AsEnumerable<Ingredient>();
```

**Update**

A pure LINQ based solution will suffice as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only if you have some way to transform a Match to an Ingredient.  Since there isn't a generic way to do this, you'll probably need to give your method a bit of help.  For example, your method could take a `Func<Match, Ingredient>` to perform the mapping:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable<T>(this MatchCollection mc, Func<Match, T> maker)
{
  foreach (Match m in mc)
    yield return maker(m);
}
```

and you could then call this as follows:

```
var ingredients = matches.AsEnumerable<Ingredient>(m => new Ingredient { Name = m.Value });
```

You can also bypass creating your own method and just use Select, with the Cast operator to deal with the weak typing of MatchCollection:

```
var ingredients = matches.Cast<Match>()
                         .Select(m => new Ingredient { Name = m.Value });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this (with `System.Linq` namespace):

```
public class Ingredient
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static class MatchCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable<T>(this MatchCollection mc, Func<Match, T> converter)
    {
        return (mc).Cast<Match>().Select(converter).ToList();
    }
}
```

and can be used like this:

```
    var matches = new Regex("([a-z])+,?").Matches("tomato,potato,carrot");

    var ingredients = matches.AsEnumerable<Ingredient>(match => new Ingredient { Name = match.Value });
```

Answer (score 2):

You could first cast it...

```
matches.Cast<Match>()
```

...and then transform the resulting `IEnumerable<Match>` however you want using LINQ.